# Solving double (n-tuple) multivariate integrals in R

Tags: r, integral

I would like to write a code to solve this kind of equations:

[image: equation to solve]

For that I wrote the code below, however it does not solve the problem. Do you have any ideas about the possibility to solve this kind of integrals in R?

```
t_0 = 15
mu = 0.1
lambda = 0.8
f = function(x1,x2) exp(mu*(x1+x2))*dexp(log(lambda)*(x1+x2))
f_comp = function(x2) f(x1,x2)
f_1 = function(x1) {integrate(f_comp,upper = t_0, lower = x1)}
result = integrate(f = f_1, lower = 0, upper = t_0)$value
```

---------  edit:

Given the answer below, I adapt the code to my example, but I still think is not the correct one, at least the value 0 for the integral does not make sense.

```
integrate(function(x1) {
  sapply(x1, function(x1){
    integrate(function(x2)  exp(mu*(x1+x2))*dexp(log(lambda)*(x1+x2)), lower = x1, upper = t_0)$value
  })
}, 0, t_0)
```

by the way, I would like to buid a general procedure for that (that is why I just not calculate the integral by hand). That is not only double integrals, but also n-tuples integrals, so I need a general procedure for this kind of calculations.

Comment: Are you sure that the R definition of the function `f` is correct? I have my doubts.  You may find an answer  in [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-October/059494.html).

Comment: @Bhas this is useful, thanks. I still do not get correct values but at least the code does not have errors anymore....

Comment: I meant that given the math formula you give I do not think that what you have coded in R as function `f` is correct. Why `log`? Where is the `1-....`?

Comment: dexp is defined as [1-exp()] and exp(log(lambda)) = lambda. The formula is not the important part of this question though.

Comment: I don't think that `dexp` is defined in the way you present. The R help says that `dexp` is defined as `lambda * exp(-lambda*x)`

Comment: ah, yes, you are right, I mean pexp(). as I said the formula is not important though, the calculation of multiple integrals is my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a picture of the domain of integration. This is a simplex (a triangle) with vertices (0,0), (0,t0), (t0,t0). To evaluate an integral on a simplex, the `SimplicialCubature` package is the way to go.

```
t0 = 15
mu = 0.1
lambda = 0.8

library(SimplicialCubature)
f <- function(xy){
  x <- xy[1]; y <- xy[2]
  exp(-mu*(x+y)) * (1-exp(-lambda*(x+y))) 
}
S <- cbind(c(0,0), c(0,t0), c(t0,t0))
adaptIntegrateSimplex(f, S)$integral
# 29.55906

integrate(function(x1) {
  sapply(x1, function(x1){
    integrate(function(x2) exp(-mu*(x1+x2))*(1-exp(-lambda*(x1+x2))), lower = x1, 
              upper = t0)$value
  })
}, 0, t0)$value
# 29.55906
```